# Dual monitor does not work

Tags: multiple-monitors, 17.04

I installed Ubuntu 17.04. I have previously been using Debian. In the system settings, the Monitor button is not there. In Debian, that is how I  used 2 monitors. How do I access this menu in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Click in the power icon at right corner of your taskbar and chose "System Settings". You can access "Displays" icon when you open System Settings: 
[image]